Does Elden Ring have a level cap?
Does Elden Ring have a level cap? If so, was it changed when Shadow of the Erdtree released?
What is it (if there is one)?

I don't know about Shadow of the Erdtree, but before the DLC the level cap was simply the maximum possible level you can reach by increasing all of your 8 stats to the maximum value of 99.
Considering the Wretch starts at level 1 with 10 points in each stat for a total of 80 points, the maximum possible level for the game is 8 * 99 - 80 + 1 = 713
This is confirmed by several sources [1, 2, 3]. To reach that level, you would need almost 1.7 billion runes, which is a massive grind.
